# Recursive java.util.Properties references

Tags: java, recursion, properties

## Background

A subclass of `java.util.Properties` attempts to recursively resolve configured properties:

```
prop_a=Prop A is ${prop_b} 
prop_b=Prop B is ${prop_c} 
prop_c=Prop C.
```

After reading the file, `prop_a` should be `Prop A is Prop B is Prop C`.

## Property Reference Semantics

Nest properties are not allowed, making the following invalid:

```
${property_name_a ${property_name_b}}
```

A valid property is:

```
name=Text for ${property_a}, followed by ${property_b}.
```

## Source Code

Code that handles parsing:

```
/**
 * This will throw an IllegalArgumentException if there are mismatched
 * braces.
 *
 * @param s - The string with zero or more ${} references to resolve.
 * @return The value of the string, with all substituted values made.
 */
public String resolve( String s ) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( 256 );
  Stack<StringBuffer> stack = new Stack<StringBuffer>();
  int len = s.length();

  for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    char c = s.charAt( i );

    switch( c ) {
      case '$': {
        if( i + 1 < len && s.charAt( i + 1 ) == '{' ) {
          stack.push( sb );
          sb = new StringBuffer( 256 );
          i++;
        }
        break;
      }

      case '}': {
        if( stack.isEmpty() ) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "unexpected '}'" );
        }

        String name = sb.toString();

        sb = stack.pop();
        sb.append( super.getProperty( name, null ) );
        break;
      }

      default: {
        sb.append( c );
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "missing '}'" );
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

## Question

How would you simplify the code and detect/avoid infinite recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You say "recursively resolve", but in fact `resolve` is not recursive. It returns `Prop A is Prop B is ${prop_c}` instead of `Prop A is Prop B is Prop C`, if you call it with `Prop A is ${prop_b}`. If you call it with `prop_a`, as advertised, it returns `prop_a`.
- You allow nested `${}` in you syntax. What is your semantics of it?
- Do you have any test cases for this. The bug and Unclear semantics of nested parens for instance, strongly indicate you should have.
- Since you access the super class through its public interface, namely the the singe call to the `super.getProperty` you could instead pass the properties as a parameter. It will improve usability. Then you can make the static, if you wish. Since the method does not refer to any instance members otherwise.
- `StringBuffer` and `Stack` have built in synchronization, whose overhead you can avoid by using `StringBuilder` and `ArrayList`.

Here is the test code to save others some effort:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Stack;


public class Main {
    public static String resolve(Properties props,  String s ) {
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( 256 );
          Stack<StringBuffer> stack = new Stack<StringBuffer>();
          int len = s.length();

          for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            char c = s.charAt( i );

            switch( c ) {
              case '$': {
                if( i + 1 < len && s.charAt( i + 1 ) == '{' ) {
                  stack.push( sb );
                  sb = new StringBuffer( 256 );
                  i++;
                }
                break;
              }

              case '}': {
                if( stack.isEmpty() ) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException( "unexpected '}'" );
                }

                String name = sb.toString();

                sb = stack.pop();
                sb.append( props.get(name) );
                break;
              }

              default: {
                sb.append( c );
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          if( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "missing '}'" );
          }

          return sb.toString();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("prop_a", "Prop A is ${prop_b}"); 
        props.setProperty("prop_b", "Prop B is ${prop_c}"); 
        props.setProperty("prop_c", "Prop C.");

        System.out.println(resolve(props, "Prop A is ${prop_b}"));
        System.out.println(resolve(props, "prop_a"));
        System.out.println(resolve(props, "${prop_a}"));
        System.out.println(resolve(props, "${${prop_b}}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: A bug exists in both of our implementations: `${prop_a} {0}` should resolve successfully.